# Elastic search aggregation pagination issue

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, aggregation

How do i perform a query similar to this one in elasticsearch?

```
SELECT field FROM table GROUP BY field OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10;
```

Thank for the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control the elasticsearch aggregation results with From / Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038131/how-to-control-the-elasticsearch-aggregation-results-with-from-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't (yet).

There's an open issue titled ["Paging aggregation support"](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915) that should take care of this feature soon. As you can see that issue is two years old, still open and got many +1 from many people. It's still not slated for any releases yet, though.

In the meantime, you can retrieve your aggregation with `size: 20` and then on the client side only consider the last 10 terms.

Comment: It helped me to not search for an answer, but thanks anyways :)

Comment: This feature was added in 5.2 FYI

Comment: @JohnJones if you're referring to [partitionable aggregations](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21487), it's a little different than pagination, but it helps achieve pretty much the same goal than pagination.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm referring too. :)